# How can I measure SQL Azure bandwidth usage per client?

Tags: .net, azure-sql-database

I have an SQL Azure database that multiple client programs are connecting to. I would like to log the network usage of the SQL Azure traffic **per client**. Is there a better alternative then aggregating the BytesReceived/ByteSent connection statistics?

Answer (score 0):

You can query usage per database, but I don't think you can segment it any further than that.